# Remove WordPress WooCommerce Reviews from custom pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Ive created a custom woo-commerce carousel to use as a visual composer element but when I put it on a page the woo-commerce reviews comments section is automatically placed underneath it.

Any ideas how I can remove this or what is triggering it to appear ?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: have you link of your website ?

Comment: also please provide the screenshot where would you like to remove review and commets exactly

Answer (score 0):

To remove comments and review from single product page login to your admin end then open your products->quick edit and then uncheck the comment section check images, please

[image]

[image]

and if you want to done through coding then add below functions into your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wcs_woo_remove_reviews_tab', 98 );
    function wcs_woo_remove_reviews_tab($tabs) {
    unset($tabs['reviews']);
    return $tabs;
}
```